# Reading large Excel array into MATLAB

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, xlsread

So I have a huge excel file with 210 columns from(A all the way to CK)-Each of these columns have 80000-300000 values.I want to read this into a MATLAB array.I have two problems:

1.Is there any way that I can **loop through the letters iteratively**(from A to CK)?

2.When I try to read the file as a whole it says **no storage**-but I am able to create a matrix of ones of size-300000*210....So Im a bit puzzled and dont know what to do..??

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show what you tried. Also make sure your data is all numeric if you compare its storage size to a matrix of ones.

Answer (score 1):

Save in the .csv format from EXCEL, then use load -ascii in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Excel column with the option `xlRange` of `xlsread` ([doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)).

And both the output `num = xlsread(...)` and `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(...)` duplicate the information being read in several variables (type `edit xlsread` in the command window).